# SQLite 3 duplicated rows violating unique contraint

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite3 database that is storing textual data. The schema specifies a unique constraint on a text column (URL). The frontend continuously tries to reinsert items with the same value (the source is a RSS feed queried every 10 minutes, so posts may reappear) which is prevented by the unique constraint.

Recently all rows were inserted into a new database due to a corruption issue using a script. Unfortunately, the rows inserted by the script somehow differ in the URL such that a few recent items from the RSS feed were reinserted (exactly once, so further inserts were prevented by the unique constraint). The URL is the extact same - no spaces. A script fetching an original and a duplicate and comparing their URL using equality returns true. Yet if I query the database using

```
select count(url) from post
group by url
having count(url) > 1;
```

there are no results! So internally, something must be different. I assume there is something encoding related going on and the URLs of "fresh" posts parsed from the RSS feed are different from the ones read from the old database and reinserted.

How can I inspect the internal state of SQLite, i.e. the actual bytes of a row, or get any sort of insight into this issue? I am totally stumped and would like to understand this problem.

The SQLite version is 3.26.0 2018-12-01 12:34:55 bf8c1b2b7a5960c282e543b9c293686dccff272512d08865f4600fb58238alt1.

Edit:

I have found a way to query the database such that it returns all duplicated pairs:

```
select p1.id, p2.id from post as p1, post as p2
where cast(p1.url as text) == cast(p2.url as text)
  and p1.id != p2.id and p1.id < p2.id;
```

This returns the 42 duplicates. The cast is necessary (no results if it is left out) but should be a no-op since url is (or should be) text.

Comment: Are you sure that the script you use to check for duplicates is correct?

Comment: Yes. I iterate over all columns and it returns false only for the id (which is an autoincremented integer) . All other columns are identical, including the URL. I use Sequel, a Ruby library, to connect to the database which may affect the outcome.

Comment: While you iterate, with that script, print the duplicate values and inspect them with a hex editor.

Comment: The bytes are identical. When I hex-edit the database file, I find 7 occurences of the same (duplicated) row. The URL of an unduplicated post occurs 6 times. This probably means nothing...

Comment: What happens if you change your query to use `count(*)` instead of `count(url)` (while keeping `group by url` the same)?

Comment: Does not change anything :(

Comment: Does running a [`PRAGMA integrity_check`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check) find anything?

Comment: Nope, result is "ok"

Comment: Maybe one of the urls is inserted as a text value and one as a blob, so they never compare equal as far as sqlite cares. Add `typeof(p1.id)` and `typeof(p2.id)` to that duplicate finding query.

Comment: You are right, the old posts have a blob url. But the schema specifies text as a data type. Why does SQLite not convert to text?